# Can I Install SQL Server 2008 R2 express edition on Windows xp 32bit?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-xp, sql-server-2008-express

I am trying since 2 days. I was able to Install but I Cant see my all services in 'SQL Server Configuration Manager and I cannot access sql server management studio.
It works fine on my windows 7 laptop and it have all the services. 
Xp have only 'SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS)' running and 'SQL SERVER AGENT(SQLEXPRESS)' and 'SQL SERVER Browser' stopped. I right clicked and tried to start but start is disabled. I am not sure whether this is installation issue or because of windows xp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a list of supported operating systems and requirments [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=SQL.105).aspx#SE32).
I checked for you and XP Professional service pack 3 is in the list.
You can try if updating your service pack works?

Comment: It have 'Windows XP Professional SP3' and mine is 'Windows XP Professional version 2002 Service pack 2'. I think SP is the problem. Whats your take?